# Output of the svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

When i add svelte component on page, i create the new exemplar of class.

```js
import ComponentA from "./Component.svelte";
let component = new ComponentA({...});


<ComponentA/>
```

And every time component destroying and created again. 
 
But I need to save the state of the component. 
(example: the display of blocks, position of blocks, text,  and much more)
When I create new exemplar, I can put it in global variable. Can I output it from global? Is that real?

Comment: Have you tried with stores? https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

Comment: I can put created exemplar in a store, but i don't know how that exemplar output in a root component from store.
Or, i need show all components and do unnesessary components hide.

I know, i can does create div containers, output all components in a containers, and hide unnesessary containers. But i think thats wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, learn about [stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores).

### Example

for example, to save the scrolling position in your App.svelte component (and not lose them if you change the component or ...):
export a variable in your stores.js

```
  export const AppY = writable(0);
```

then bind your Y position (of your App.svelte component with svelte:scrollY) to a variable.

in your App.svelte :

```
  import { AppY } from "../stores.js";
  // some code
  let Y = ... // bind your svelte:scrollY  here
  $: $AppY = Y;
```

Now you have the scrollY position in your writable store. to save this position for long time, you can use *localStorage*.